# aggregateWindow aligned to specified timezone

Tags: timezone, influxdb, flux, timezone-offset

Given the following query in Influxdb's Flux language:

```
from(bucket: "some-great-metrics")
   |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
   |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum)
   |> yield()
```

Assuming my current timezone is `PST`. How to ensure that `aggregateWindow` respect the beginning and end of the `1mo` duration in this specific timezone (`PST`)?

Searching in the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/) does not bring so much light to me, so far.

Comment: Having the same issue and also no solution. It seems that for today this is not implemented yet. See: https://github.com/influxdata/flux/issues/406#issuecomment-667986195 for a basic workaround. But it wont work for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like Influx 2.1 comes with a new [Flux timezone package](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/timezone/)

You can try to upgrade to 2.1 and add this before your query:

```
import "timezone"

option location = timezone.location(name: "America/Los_Angeles")
```

Answer (score 1):

Things are getting more and more interesting with Flux. Besides the `option location` that allows you to assign one time zone to an entire query (applicable to the original question, but not applicable in general), many functions that operate on time (including `aggregateWindow()`) now offer a `location` argument that allows you to operate with multiple time zones in a single streams of table. Unfortunately some of these are still undocumented.

In case, I've written an extensive review [here](https://medium.com/@marcodb.dev/time-zones-flux-and-javascript-part-ii-c4af6e459ae3).